Is there an official tool to keep an Ubuntu system clean and optimized
I have found several tools that do partial cleaning but none comprehensively or officially from Ubuntu.

Please be more specific on what you want cleaned, and what tools  you have been looking at.

Unlike others o/s, I have found the Linux system to be always clean. If I have clutter, this is a user issue: such as browser cache, or unused apps.These I delete myself. For a general clean... For deb files, the terminal command works well: sudo apt autoremove.  For flatpak: flatpak uninstall --unused. If I know I have risk of malware, I will use an antivirus occasionally.

"Optimized" depends on purpose.

Ubuntu Cleaner is a tool which makes it easy to clean up Ubuntu so that it's more like a freshly installed system.

There are a number of steps to installation:
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gerardpuig/ppa -y      
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install ubuntu-cleaner

This instructional resource explains the process in further detail.
